# Problem obtaining data from a MongoDB object and putting it in discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to convert data from a mongoDB object and paste it in discord, I can successfully obtain the data and log it in the console but when I try to paste it in discord my bot sends: "[object Object]" and I've tried converting it into a json file but im not getting any luck with that either, If anyone could help that would  be amazing!

Code:

```
  let name = args[0]

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("register");
    var query = { name: name };
    dbo.collection("registers").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      message.channel.send(result)
      db.close();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I've never worked with MongoDB before but it seems like `result` is an array of objects. If Discord.js receives an array it sends each element of the array, so it converts the object to a string (`[object Object]`). Try sending `JSON.stringify(result)`.

Comment: I tried doing that but now instead of [object Object] im getting [ ]

Comment: Ok, Turns out that did work just I was trying to enter something  wrong, I Entered the players ID into the database and searched for the players ID instead of their name  and this solution worked.